# Position Dialog Popup as Sidebar using PrimeNG

Tags: css, popup, angular8, primeng, sidebar

I want to have a sidebar which will have some content in Header-Content-Footer style. Purpose is that I need a specific title, backgroud color etc for header and action buttons in footer with dynamic content in middle. However, p-sidebar doesnt offer these templates so I am trying to use popup for this and make it look like sidebar. I am able to achive header and footer styling I needed using popup but I am not able to position it on right side as sidebar.

**So What I need is popup shown here :**

[image: What I get]

**to look like this** :

[image: What I want]

I am no expert in CSS so any input is highly awaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
body .ui-widget-overlay{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

body .ui-dialog{
  width: 50vw;
  z-index: 11008;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```